# How to read Http response header in angular

Tags: angular, http, http-headers

This is my angular service class code.I have called restful web service in this class ,response is coming . Response header has JWT web token I want to read response header and take JWT web token in this authUser service function. how to do it?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ResponseBeanModule} from '../../module/responsebean/responsebean.module';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { this._prepare()}
  private userUrl = 'http://192.168.1.152:8080/api/user/';

  endpointUrl: String;
  responseBeanModule: ResponseBeanModule = new ResponseBeanModule();
  options: any;
  headers: any;

  _prepare () {
    this.endpointUrl = this.userUrl;
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.options = {
      headers: this.headers,
      observe: 'body'
    };
  }



  public authUser(loginBean): Promise<ResponseBeanModule> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(this.userUrl, loginBean, this.options).subscribe(
        (data) => {
         alert(JSON.stringify(data));
         this.responseBeanModule = JSON.parse(data['_body'])
          return resolve( this.responseBeanModule );
        },
        (err) => {
          return reject(err);
        }
      );
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: This looks a bad way. First you should correct the way you are calling service. For starters, use httpClient, use observable instead of promise, etc

Comment: Please take a look at the official docs. https://angular.io/guide/http and use `HttpClient`. `Http` has been deprecated for ages. Also I see no reason to use promises. When you have that part done, then take a look at how you can read the headers from the same link as above (when using `HttpClient`, NOT `Http`). Here the exact segment: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response For future, please read the documentation first :)

Comment: I notice you're doing a post. I would also like to post and find the response headers in the object. I attempted to use the observe options using 'response' in an HttpClient.post() function call -- it sort of worked but ... I logged an issue about this on github, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44127 so I hope there's some traction on this answer or even a bug fix!

Answer (score 0):

Either this is a broken feature of Angular's HttpClient, or they never intended for you to read more headers than just the `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` --
I can only read those headers using either HTTP POST or HTTP GET:

```
  login(username = "", password = "") {
    return this.httpClient
      .post(`${environment.apiLocation}redfish/v1/SessionService/Sessions`,
        { username, password },
        {observe: 'response'})
      .pipe(
        map(response => {
          const keys = response.headers.keys();
          let headers = keys.map(key =>
            `${key}: ${response.headers.get(key)}`);
          this.logger.log('response headers', headers);
```